# Binary to dec and hex in C

Tags: c, binary, hex, decimal

I would like to create function that will return numbers in hexidecimal. But I am getting some wrong numbers after changing to decimal numbers. In output, the first number is binary, second one also binary but in int format, and third one should be decimal. But I am getting wrong numbers in decimal (see the second line, where it shoud be 156, not 220). Could anyone explain me what am i doing wrong and how can I get right numbers? Thank you. Here is my output:

[image]

```
    char *encrypted = calloc((size_t)TEXT_LEN*3, sizeof(char));
int number[TEXT_LEN];
index=0;
for(int i=0;i<TEXT_LEN;i++){

    number[i]=atoi(binary[i]);

    printf("%s ",binary[i]);
    printf("%d ",number[i]);
    printf("%d\n",(unsigned char)number[i]);

    sprintf(encrypted+index,"%x ",(unsigned char)number[i]);

    index+=3;
}

printf("%s\n",encrypted);
free(encrypted);
```

EDIT: I found solution in comments, and I fixed it by using function strtol in line:

number[i] = strtol ( binary[i], NULL, 2);

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please don't post images of code. Instead, post the code itself.

Comment: So what is wrong? You didn’t explain that.

Comment: What the `binary` has inside? How it is created?

Comment: The third number in the output (in line) should be decimal representation of binary. But I am getting wrong numbers (see 220)

Comment: What is the range of the number values ? Eight bits should be enough for a two digit hex number. Seems to me that the output does not match with the code.

Comment: @Werner number is created from binary, and binary is string consisting of 8 digits (ones and zeros)
user3121023 I can try it. Do you think that integer is small to contain 8 digits?

Comment: `char *encrypted = calloc((size_t)TEXT_LEN*3, sizeof(char));` is too small by 1.  Use `char *encrypted = calloc(TEXT_LEN*3u + 1, sizeof *encrypted);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of number values smaller than 16 the written string length is two and at the end the char '\0' is inserted. Use either a fixed size

```
sprintf(encrypted+index,"%02x ", number[i]);
index += 3;
```

or use the return value from the sprintf function which is the written string length to increment the index

```
index += sprintf(encrypted+index,"%x ", number[i]);
```

I would prefer a combination of both

```
index += sprintf(encrypted+index,"%02x ", number[i]);
```

Based on the eight character string in binary the method of user3121023 above will give you the right decimal number

```
number[i] = strtol(binary[i], NULL, 2);
printf("%s ", binary[i]); // 1st col
printf("%d\n", number[i]); // 2nd col
```

Comment: Thank you, but the main thing I have to fix, is conversion to decimal and heximal. In the second line of output, you can see that the binary number is 220, and it is wrong. I am about to get 156, which is decimal representation of 10011100

Answer (score 1):

In the second line of output, I wrote a C plus plus program to explain your doubt:

```
int value = 10011100;
cout<<bitset<sizeof(int)*8>(value)<<value<<endl;    // 0000000010011000110000011101110010011100
unsigned char va = (unsigned char)value;
cout<<bitset<sizeof(unsigned char)*8>(va)<<endl;    // 11011100
```

the decimal number 10011100 convert to binary number `10011000110000011101110010011100`, then it is put in unsigned char, we get `11011100`, it is 220.